# How to get datas from this table 'directory_currency_rate'

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, collection, currency-rates

Table contains these columns.

[image]

I need to get data from this table `'directory_currency_rate'`

which is come under this directory

```
/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php
/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model//ResourceModel/Currency.php
```

This model file does not have any `collection.php` file so can't able to get datas from this table.

Anyone know how to get data from this table ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can not get using any class or methods, then you can use SQL select statement as below example.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('directory_currency_rate');

// SELECT DATA 
$fields = array('rate');
$sql = $connection->select()                      
                  ->from($tableName, $fields) // to select some particular fields                  
                  ->where('currency_from = ?', 'USD')
                  ->where('currency_to = ?', 'EUR'); // adding WHERE condition with AND
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @kishan. without using query i need to get datas from that table. is there any possibilities ?

Comment: May we know reason for fetching data without query ?

Comment: if i use query it showing codingstandard warning like i shown here  102 | WARNING | Possible raw SQL statement "Select * FROM `"
     |         | detected.
 105 | WARNING | fetchAll can be memory inefficient for large data
     |         | sets.

Comment: for this i am trying alternative method.if i get datas through collecton file.i can use addFieldtoFilter. and i can fetch my required datas from that table

Comment: You can use condition for filter as per my updated answer.

Comment: You should not use ObjectManager in this way. Please see any of the numerous posts on accomplishing this same thing the correct M2 way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Magento\Directory\Api\CurrencyInformationAcquirerInterface` and its method `getCurrencyInfo` which return all available currencies and its conversion rates.

On the my test host it returns next result:

[image: result]

If you want to take plain response from the database I'll recommend you to write own query.

Here the code example which can be run from external script (outside Magento):

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$currencyInformation = $obj->get('Magento\Directory\Api\CurrencyInformationAcquirerInterface');
$currenciesAndRates = $currencyInformation->getCurrencyInfo();
```

In your class you should use di: add the `Magento\Directory\Api\CurrencyInformationAcquirerInterface` in its construct method and use it.

Comment: can you please explain briefly?

Comment: is there any way to get this table datas by using collection.php ?

Comment: Alternatively you can use SQL select as per my answer. Please check.

Comment: I think answer is no, there is no way to get that result as a collection, because collection require the id which missed in this table :( In case you want take direct response from the table please use answer given by @kishan-patadia .

Comment: thanks for your script. @SergeyUchuhlebov script runs full collection but i didn't get the particular table datas.

Comment: As I said, to get all data directly from the table you should use answer given by Kishan Patadia. This is the right way to obtain this data.